# Godot unable to build C# scripts : The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7 were not found

Tags: c#, mono, godot

I started a toy project with the Godot Game engine v3.2.2 using Mono.
I just tried to compile a very simple C# script, and the build fails with the following error thrown in the logs:

```
Project "Bloopers.sln" (Build target(s)):
Message: Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Project "Bloopers.csproj" (default targets):
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.402/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [/home/mrblack/src/games/godot/godot_v3/lab/first_game_dotnet/Bloopers.csproj]
    MakeDir: Creating directory ".mono/temp/obj/Debug/".
Done building project "Bloopers.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

Done building project "Bloopers.sln" -- FAILED.

I have Mono v.6.12 installed.   Any insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated !
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I just figured it out.
I have both frameworks installed:

- Mono
- dotnet core

Apparently Godot detects both and gives you an option between the two.  By default
it chooses dotnet core.   Godot at this moment only officially supports Mono.

To ensure you are using Mono:
Editor -> Editor Settings
Mono -> Builds
Select "MSBuild(Mono)" in the drop down menu.

Now my game builds.